# How to generate a CSS color that is some specific percentage lighter/darker using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors

Let's say I have a color of #404040. How can I generate a new color hex code which is either lighter or darker by 20% (or another given percentage)? I need this for generating a color to apply on hover.

The color being applied changes based on the chosen theme, therefore it is not possible to use another class or `:hover` with a predefined color value.

Comment: Will the color always be a hex color?  Is it possible to convert them all to RGB, or even better, to HSV?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

```
var pad = function(num, totalChars) {
    var pad = '0';
    num = num + '';
    while (num.length < totalChars) {
        num = pad + num;
    }
    return num;
};

// Ratio is between 0 and 1
var changeColor = function(color, ratio, darker) {
    // Trim trailing/leading whitespace
    color = color.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/, '');

    // Expand three-digit hex
    color = color.replace(
        /^#?([a-f0-9])([a-f0-9])([a-f0-9])$/i,
        '#$1$1$2$2$3$3'
    );

    // Calculate ratio
    var difference = Math.round(ratio * 256) * (darker ? -1 : 1),
        // Determine if input is RGB(A)
        rgb = color.match(new RegExp('^rgba?\\(\\s*' +
            '(\\d|[1-9]\\d|1\\d{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])' +
            '\\s*,\\s*' +
            '(\\d|[1-9]\\d|1\\d{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])' +
            '\\s*,\\s*' +
            '(\\d|[1-9]\\d|1\\d{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])' +
            '(?:\\s*,\\s*' +
            '(0|1|0?\\.\\d+))?' +
            '\\s*\\)$'
        , 'i')),
        alpha = !!rgb && rgb[4] != null ? rgb[4] : null,

        // Convert hex to decimal
        decimal = !!rgb? [rgb[1], rgb[2], rgb[3]] : color.replace(
            /^#?([a-f0-9][a-f0-9])([a-f0-9][a-f0-9])([a-f0-9][a-f0-9])/i,
            function() {
                return parseInt(arguments[1], 16) + ',' +
                    parseInt(arguments[2], 16) + ',' +
                    parseInt(arguments[3], 16);
            }
        ).split(/,/),
        returnValue;

    // Return RGB(A)
    return !!rgb ?
        'rgb' + (alpha !== null ? 'a' : '') + '(' +
            Math[darker ? 'max' : 'min'](
                parseInt(decimal[0], 10) + difference, darker ? 0 : 255
            ) + ', ' +
            Math[darker ? 'max' : 'min'](
                parseInt(decimal[1], 10) + difference, darker ? 0 : 255
            ) + ', ' +
            Math[darker ? 'max' : 'min'](
                parseInt(decimal[2], 10) + difference, darker ? 0 : 255
            ) +
            (alpha !== null ? ', ' + alpha : '') +
            ')' :
        // Return hex
        [
            '#',
            pad(Math[darker ? 'max' : 'min'](
                parseInt(decimal[0], 10) + difference, darker ? 0 : 255
            ).toString(16), 2),
            pad(Math[darker ? 'max' : 'min'](
                parseInt(decimal[1], 10) + difference, darker ? 0 : 255
            ).toString(16), 2),
            pad(Math[darker ? 'max' : 'min'](
                parseInt(decimal[2], 10) + difference, darker ? 0 : 255
            ).toString(16), 2)
        ].join('');
};
var lighterColor = function(color, ratio) {
    return changeColor(color, ratio, false);
};
var darkerColor = function(color, ratio) {
    return changeColor(color, ratio, true);
};

// Use
var darker = darkerColor('rgba(80, 75, 52, .5)', .2);
var lighter = lighterColor('rgba(80, 75, 52, .5)', .2);
```

Now handles RGB(A) input, as well as hex (3 digit or 6).

Comment: Technically speaking, to get an x% lighter or darker color from an RGB value, you would have to convert it to HSL, reduce or increase (L)ightness by x% and then convert back to RGB. I am not sure that reducing the individual RGB values like you do here will result in the same color. Not to get into how the human eye perceives changes in lightness which might introduce a non-linear scale for the equivalent of an x% *perceived* change in lightness :)

Comment: That's true, this is a very naive approach

Answer (score 8):

You could make a partially-transparent white or black PNG and overlay (underlay?) it on hover:

```
div.button {
  background-color: #404040;
}
body>div.button:hover {
  background-image: url('blackpixel.png');
}
```

No JS required.

Comment: Then add more code to support IE 6. Then add another option for lighter. Then.....

Comment: LOL, that didn't resolve any of the problems I listed. It has limited utility, but if that's all you need, sure go for it

Answer (score 3):

From [*How to Calculate Lighter or Darker Hex Colors in JavaScript*](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-generate-lighter-darker-color/) by Craig Buckler, September 6, 2011:

> ```
> function ColorLuminance(hex, lum) {
>   // validate hex string
>   hex = String(hex).replace(/[^0-9a-f]/gi, '');
>   if (hex.length < 6) {
>       hex = hex[0]+hex[0]+hex[1]+hex[1]+hex[2]+hex[2];
>   }
>   lum = lum || 0;
>   // convert to decimal and change luminosity
>   var rgb = "#", c, i;
>   for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
>       c = parseInt(hex.substr(i*2,2), 16);
>       c = Math.round(Math.min(Math.max(0, c + (c * lum)), 255)).toString(16);
>       rgb += ("00"+c).substr(c.length);
>   }
>   return rgb;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You basically just need to add (for lighter) or subtract (for darker) equal amounts from each of R, G, B components.

Take a look at [Domino 2.0](http://blog.lotusnotes.be/domino/archive/2007-08-04-javascript-color-functions.html) which is a small javascript library that does just that.

Comment: i used :hover and calculated with my brain, but this did the trick for me

Answer (score 1):

Here is my way of doing it using replace and split.

```
var CO='';

$('#HoverMe').hover(function(){  
    CO=$(this).css('backgroundColor');
 
    var CC= $(this).css('backgroundColor').replace('rgb(','').replace(')','').split(',');

    var Change=0.2;

    var CR=Math.floor((CC[0]*Change)+parseInt(CC[0]));

    var CG=Math.floor((CC[1]*Change)+parseInt(CC[1]));

    var CB=Math.floor((CC[2]*Change)+parseInt(CC[2]));

    $(this).css('background','rgb('+CR+','+CG+','+CB+')');
},

function(){
    $(this).css('background',CO);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For this solution you need two elements the outer one defines your color, the inner one is used for the highlighting. In my case I have something like this:

```
<div class="button"><a href="#">Hi Color</a></div>
```

Then you define in CSS:

```
.button {
   display: inline-block;
   background-color: blue;
}

.button a {
   display: inline-block;
}

.button a:hover {
   background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/869wg/2/)

Answer (score 0):

This is just a modification of [eyelidlessness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507931/generate-lighter-darker-color-in-css-using-javascript/1507987#1507987)' answer, since I saw the same function twice

```
var pad = function(num, totalChars) {
    var pad = '0';
    num = num + '';
    while (num.length < totalChars) {
        num = pad + num;
    }
    return num;
};

// Ratio is between 0 and 1
var changeColor = function(color, ratio, darker) {
    var difference = Math.round(ratio * 255) * (darker ? -1 : 1),
        minmax     = darker ? Math.max : Math.min,
        decimal    = color.replace(
            /^#?([a-z0-9][a-z0-9])([a-z0-9][a-z0-9])([a-z0-9][a-z0-9])/i,
            function() {
                return parseInt(arguments[1], 16) + ',' +
                    parseInt(arguments[2], 16) + ',' +
                    parseInt(arguments[3], 16);
            }
        ).split(/,/);
    return [
        '#',
        pad(minmax(parseInt(decimal[0], 10) + difference, 0).toString(16), 2),
        pad(minmax(parseInt(decimal[1], 10) + difference, 0).toString(16), 2),
        pad(minmax(parseInt(decimal[2], 10) + difference, 0).toString(16), 2)
    ].join('');
};
var lighterColor = function(color, ratio) {
    return changeColor(color, ratio, false);
};
var darkerColor = function(color, ratio) {
    return changeColor(color, ratio, true);
};

// Use
var darker = darkerColor('#404040', .2);
var lighter = lighterColor('#404040', .2);
```

Comment: And then the second argument would be 255. Heh, plus I updated mine to support RGB(A).

Comment: ...and still broken! you're missing `darker ? 0 : 255` condition in your `minmax` call, so it produces black most of the time!

Answer (score 0):

perhaps [jquery.colorhelpers.js](http://code.google.com/p/flot/source/browse/trunk/jquery.colorhelpers.js) functions for scale and add would help?
I'm trying to find better examples than are found in-line for the flot source code, however.

Comment: That library has no dependency on jQuery yet still decides to pollute the `$` namespace?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you missed http://www.safalra.com/web-design/javascript/colour-handling-and-processing/ . It supports HSV and HSL colors and convert between them and between RGB values.

HSV and HSL are much more "human friendly" representations of colors, so using them making a lighter color, a darker one, a more or less intense one, or finding the color with the best contrast is extremely simple.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way just using CSS, similar to Wander Nauta's solution, but without using an image.  If you can change the html, simply put a div behind the area you want to change with the original color set as the background.  Then, you can set the area you're concerned about with a semi-transparent white or black background, and you'll lighten or darken your element.

I'm guessing it has its limitations, but it works great for me.

Comment: Also, if you're only looking to lighten, and don't care about IE<8, simply set the opacity value on hover.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean server side JS then you can use [Stylus](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/functions.html) which is a CSS preprocessor with built-in functions for making colors lighter/darker etc.