# Inherit colour and then make it darker/brighter

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two div's one is .father and the other one is .child - as follows:

```
<div class="father">
  <p></p>
</div>

<div class="child">
  <p></p>
</div>
```

As you can see, the child is not inside the father (sorry if this seems doggy, the only example blinked to me). What I am trying to do; is when I give the .father a background colour lets say "background-color: #000". I want the child to inherit the colour black BUT make it brighter/darker...

I have tried to do the following:

```
.child {
  background-color: -20%;
}
```

I don't know if that is a real way, I guess it's stupid - but I need to share what I did.
I have also tried to do it using CSS transparency but that will be applied to the whole div... what if the div has text inside it?

So for example, I wrap the div .child with another div and give that div a black background, then apply transparency to the div .child - but this will apply transparency to the text as well!

**If I have added a  around the  how can I make that span inherit the colour of the div inside it? and inherit its size as well.**

Comment: This is going to be hard, and comparing colors like that is a lot harder than you seem to think. You should consider rethinking this and just hardcoding the colors.

Comment: Look into using a pre-processor such as LESS. This becomes easy then.

Comment: Does this work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625681/dynamically-change-color-to-lighter-or-darker-by-percentage-css-javascript/13722836#13722836

Comment: But what about my second idea? common guys, it seems going to work with some help!

Comment: I'm looking for something similar, but for text-colors. To make links (a-tags) a little darker than the text

Comment: The use of father and child can confuse programers and editors later in the codes life cycle and should be avoided as tags.  The use of the colour is fine and can pass so that the values are the same.  However, in javascript there is likely a way - keeping in mind that the RGB is actually three values that need adjustment.

Comment: If I have added a <span> around the <div> how can I make that span inherit the colour of the div inside it? and inherit its size as well.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid you cannot do that in pure CSS. Unless of course you work with rgba colors to make it transparent.

There is however a function in SASS (and LESS) that allows to darken/lighten colors. Take a look at these function's reference [here](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#lighten-instance_method). 
More information about SASS/SCSS: http://sass-lang.com/

Answer (score 3):

You can set for the child background the same color that for the father, and set a semitransparent pseudo element over it.

If the background of the pseudo element is semi-transparent white, the background-color gets lighter; if the pseudo element is semitransparent black, the child gets darker.

```
.father, .child { 
    background-color: red;
}

.child {
    position: relative;
}

.child:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.child:hover:after {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}
```

In this example, the child gets darker red, but turns to lighter red when hovered (and works the same if the base color is whatever you want

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5GqPX/)