# Error message fade in with background color

Tags: css

Not sure if it should be possible to do with pure CSS3..

Googled for answers but they have answers for hover which I do not need.

The form will not display errors till the user click button with empty fields and then it will fade in the error message with background color (from light to original).

Is there any easy way to do that without JQuery?

```
<div class="msg">
      <g:if test="${flash.error}">
        <div class="error">${flash.error}</div>
      </g:if>
      </div>
```

CSS

```
 .error{
  background-color: #ff9696;
  color: red;
  padding: 15px 0;
  transition: 2 opacity 2s 3s ease-in;
}
```

have been trying to make it come out in fade when clicking buttons and the fields are not filled in. but it comes out "unnaturally" (like pop out)

Comment: Reacting to user input is usually the realm of javascript. You don't *need* to use jQuery, but it makes it a ton easier. Can you post an example of your problem either a) in an edit to your question or b) on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 1):

See [My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LKBZ5/4/)

In order to make a transition work, you have to have a starting state to transition from. It's not pure CSS, but with some simple Javascript, you can trigger a transition by changing the `className` property of your error message element when the document loads.

### Example HTML

```
<body onload="showError();">
  <p class="error">Error!</p>

  <button class="error-button">Show Error</button>
</body>
```

### CSS

```
.error{
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  height:20px;
  background:#ff9696;
  color:red;
}

.error.show {
  display:block;
  background:white;
  transition:background 1s ease-in;
}

.error-button {
  position:relative;
  margin-top:30px;
}
```

### Javascript

```
var showError = function() {
  var err = document.getElementsByClassName("error")[0];

  if(err)
  {
    err.className = "error show";
  }
};
```

You could implement the `showError` function a little differently to transition multiple error messages. This way works for one message only. Note that I have set the `position` of the error message to `absolute` to prevent other elements moving around when it appears. You can try this in the fiddle by commenting out or deleting the error element.

Comment: thanks but I don't see any background coming in fade?

Comment: Ok. I thought you wanted the background to start red and fade out so you could read the white text. You can easily reverse that by swapping the background colors between `.error` and `.error.show`. If you don't see any transition, I'll have to look into it more. What browser do you use?

Comment: @AustinMillins - thanks and i swap but no transition. I use Chrome

Comment: Weird, I just tried it in Firefox and IE, too. All of them display the transition on jsfiddle. That means it must depend on local settings somehow. Anyway, jQuery's animation functions smooth over all of those differences nicely. So, jQuery is my recommendation for this.

Comment: hmm background color doesn't fade in still. i think something wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56394/discussion-between-austin-mullins-and-joe).

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to accomplish this in pure CSS. If you are trying to avoid JQuery altogether see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625681/dynamically-change-color-to-lighter-or-darker-by-percentage-css-javascript) for related problem with an interesting solution which modifies the CSS file

Answer (score 0):

If you use position absolute you can easily change the z-index and opacity so it goes back and fades. This is achieved with javascript thought and it's not easier without jQuery but the other way around.

Comment: thanks but opacity 1 will always show full color right

Comment: opacity 1 is fully visible, opacity 0 is transparent (to the point it is invisible)