# How to uniformly darken colors?

Tags: javascript, css

I display two kind of texts: one in a bright color (say, for things to do today) and another one in a darker shade (say, for things to do tomorrow). The solution I use is to assign to the relevant `div` containers a class `day` and `night`, each of carrying the appropriate color.

This works fine for a binary case of two hand picked colors.

I now want to also add colorful badges (say, categories) for each of these informational texts and would like to badges to reflect the "bright"/"dark" dichotomy: when something bears the class `today`, its badge should be in a brighter color (and darker for the class `tomorrow`).

I can of course create two classes per badge: `cooking-today`, `cooking-tomorrow`, `important-today`, `important-tomorrow`, etc. - each of them having a handcrafted color. This is hardly scalable and I would prefer that the "darkening" is done automatically, by the mere addition of a class (which would modify all the colors towards a darker version).

I do not know how to approach this since I believe that a color must be hardcoded (in the sense that a CSS `color:` definition must be specific and cannot be computed on the fly based on the existence of another class). My knowledge of HTML5/CSS/JS being minimal I would be glad to be wrong.

Comment: mix-blend-mode or background-blend-mode, via a class could help, but without any code, it is just a guess

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625681/dynamically-change-color-to-lighter-or-darker-by-percentage-css-javascript

Comment: Look into using a language that compiles into CSS, such as [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/).

Comment: @GCyrillus: thank you, I did not know about these proprieties - I will give them a try.

Comment: here was the idea http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZQaOGX

Comment: @BG101: There is a great solution in the answers to the question you linked to, using `opacity`. I just gave it a try and it looks promising: https://jsfiddle.net/tk1xghp4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this is a little off-putting if you've not used Sass before but take a look [at my example on Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EPbyZp). Sass is a great tool to "programmatically" adjust colors in this way using a base color and output the classes required. Lists and loops are fairly advanced concepts though.

**Codepen example output as straight-up HTML/CSS**

```css
.event--cooking {
  color: yellow;
  background-color: #333;
  border: 1px solid #e6e600;
}
.event--cooking.important {
  color: #b3b300;
}
.event--cooking.tomorrow {
  color: olive;
}

.event--sewing {
  color: grey;
  background-color: #333;
  border: 1px solid #737373;
}
.event--sewing.important {
  color: #5a5a5a;
}
.event--sewing.tomorrow {
  color: #404040;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="event--cooking today">Today</button>
<button type="button" class="event--cooking today important">Important Today</button>
<button type="button" class="event--cooking tomorrow important">Important Tomorrow</button>
```