# How can I make the color of an element more dark on :hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, colors

I have multiple elements in my webpage. For example multiple buttons *(which have red background color)*, links *(which have blue background color)* and etc ... .

I need to change the color of them on `:hover`. Currently I do that like this:

```css
button{
  background-color: red;
}

button:hover {
   background-color: #c80020;
}

a {
  color: blue;
}

a:hover {
  color: #082767;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button>button</button>
<a>link</a>
```

As you see, I use a more dark color than element's color on `:hover`.

All I want to know, Isn't there any color *(or approach)* to just makes an element more dark than what it is? I don't have any specific color. actually I don't care about any exact color, I just want to make an element more dark on `:hover`, just that. Any suggestion?

Comment: Use some dynamic language like SCSS.

Comment: I believe this has been [asked before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625681/dynamically-change-color-to-lighter-or-darker-by-percentage-css-javascript). SASS and LESS have `darken()` and `lighten()` functions. `a { color: #FC0; } a:hover { color: darken( #FC0, 5% );`.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman Just for that?!

Comment: @A.Wolff I don't see any possibility in purse CSS. Do you know any?

Comment: @MuhammadUsman I guess A. Wolff means using SCSS only for making sth dark isn't affordable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use hsla instead of hex-colors.

example:

```css
button{
 background-color: hsla(356, 98%, 46%, 1);
}

button:hover {
  background-color: hsla(356, 98%, 26%, 1);
}
```

```html
<button>button</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

If your using SASS, you can make use of the `darken` method to achieve the same

**SASS way below**

```
button{
  background-color: red;
}

button:hover {
   background-color: darken(red, 10%);
}
```

**CSS neat way below(CSS3)**

The best among pure CSS way, I would suggest is using **HSLA(Hue Saturation Lightness and alpha)**, this is a CSS3 feature which you can check out [here](https://css-tricks.com/yay-for-hsla/). For you it should look like

```
button{
 background-color: hsla(0, 100%, 50%, 1);
}

button:hover {
  background-color: hsla(0, 100%, 38%, 1);
}
```

**CSS ugly way below(I am sure nobody would read this)**

If you want more CSS approach for this, there are few options which you can try from here

[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/chrisboon27/pen/ACdka)

These includes

- adding a box-shadow & removing it on hover
- adding 1px translucent gif & remove it on hover
- background created as psuedo-element & it's opacity changes on hover

These are more like hacks according to me & I would not recommend but options are open :-)

Comment: Then there are few ugly way of getting it done, not what i would recommend. Link with explanation updated in my answer.

Comment: Thx for the update although ya, it is quite ugly... :)

Comment: ya i have updated a better CSS3 way of doing it as well -> HSLA

Comment: refactored the answer for others as well.

Comment: Because of the exact same values and the exactly same formattig, I'm pretty sure you copied the HSLA answer from @AndreasBoyer And it is note nice to your copy an answer and not take note about this.

Comment: LOL its not rocket science to convert `rgba(232, 2, 18, 1)` to hsla. I guess you will get the same value no matter who checks it online. not copying LOL. red is red anywhere you go. That is the first shade of red you get if you google red shades. haha. anyways changed the shade for your happiness . You can get more from [here](http://hslpicker.com/#c20000) FYI

Answer (score 0):

no, the best way is to change the color, but you can use greyscale(but i don't recommend it)

```css
button{
  background-color: red;
}

button:hover {
   background-color: #c80020;
}

a {
  color: blue;
}

a:hover {-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button>button</button>
<a>link</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this is what you're looking for:

html

```
<div class="image">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.image {
    background: url('http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/round-simple-social-icons/58/facebook.png');
    width: 58px;
    height: 58px;
    position:relative;
}
.image:hover > .overlay {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#000;
    opacity:0.5;
    border-radius:30px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6bjTQ/

Comment: This even change the content and not only the element.

Comment: @eisbehr that's slightly debatable as the answer is a minimal example. Though not a great one.