# CSS: How to change only one value using hsl color

Tags: css

Is there any way to adjust only specific values using `hsl`? For example, if I only want to change the saturation or lightness and keep the hue the same?

```
.red {
    background-color: #ff0000; /* or, hsl(0,100%,50%); */
}
.red-dark { // Adjust saturation +10% and lightness -15%
    background-color: hsl(, +10%, -15%);
}
```

Comment: In general, naming classes by their colors instead of their intended use is bad practice. However, I think what you are looking for is something like SASS which will let you assign variables for use and it seems there is build in functions that can help you out then. Similar as shown in this SO post ► http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625681/dynamically-change-color-to-lighter-or-darker-by-percentage-css-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use `javascript` or a css preprocessor like `sass`, as mentioned by Fran.

CSS is declarative and has no reference to previous condition with a few small exceptions. For the most part, it only executes what it is given.