# make color 20% whiter

Tags: java, css, colors

I have a Spring Boot application and I need to make a color more whiten. First I tried it just with transparency in CSS, but then I noticed that some places are overlapping and it is visible.

For example I have this color: #de0059

Now I want to add about 20% white into it: #e5337a

How can I do that in Java or pure CSS (not SASS or something else)?
I don't want to make the color lighter, I want to make it like transparent on a white background just without transparency.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically change color to lighter or darker by percentage CSS (Javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625681/dynamically-change-color-to-lighter-or-darker-by-percentage-css-javascript)

Comment: I don't want to make it lighter

Comment: I takes like 20 seconds, to search, you know - https://topaxi.codes/modifying-css-colors-with-the-color-function/

Comment: Well that is cssnext and not pure css

Comment: Maybe you would like to take a look at: [How to make a given color a bit darker or lighter?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/75417/how-to-make-a-given-color-a-bit-darker-or-lighter)

Comment: And also here: [Programmatically Lighten or Darken a hex color (or rgb, and blend colors)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560248/programmatically-lighten-or-darken-a-hex-color-or-rgb-and-blend-colors).

Answer (score 1):

In Java the you can do Color.brighter(), however you cannot define how much lighter you want the colour to be. Alternatively if you could do something like

```
Color col = new Color(222, 0, 89); //The RGB equivalent of #de0059
Color lighter = new Color(col.getRed() * 0.8, col.getGreen() * 0.8, col.getBlue() * 0.8);
```

If you merely want to increase the transparency, you can do

```
Color transparent = new Color(col.getRed(), col.getGreen(), col.getBlue, (255*0.8));
```

The fourth argument in the Java constructor is the alpha chanel for transparency , where 255 = completely opaque and 0 = completely transparent.

Comment: But then it's not close to 229, 52, 122. Is there way to make #de0059 0.8 transparent and combine it with white?

Comment: If you want to make it 20% whiter and 0.8 transparent you can just combine the above:

   Color whiter = new Color(Color lighter = new Color(col.getRed() * 0.8, col.getGreen() * 0.8, col.getBlue() * 0.8, 255 * 0.8);

Answer (score 0):

Quite interesting question. I don't know how to accurately measure `20% whiter` but maybe if you know the theory behind this, you can achieve the result you want with `brightness` and `contrast` css filters. I provide an example:

```css
.box {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 80px;
   height:80px;
   line-height: 80px;
   color: #ffffff;
   text-align: center;
   font-family: sans-serif;
   margin-right: 1px;
}

.box-1 {
  background-color: #de0059;
}
 
.box-2 {
  background-color: #e5337a;
}
 
.box-3 {
  background-color: #de0059;
  filter: brightness(120%) contrast(70%);
}
```

```html
<p>using pure colors</p>
<div class="box box-1">#de0059</div>
<div class="box box-2">#e5337a</div>
<br>
<p>using css filters</p>
<div class="box box-1">#de0059</div>
<div class="box box-3">calculated</div>
```

My sources:

- [Dynamically change color to lighter or darker by percentage CSS (Javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625681/dynamically-change-color-to-lighter-or-darker-by-percentage-css-javascript)
- [MDN - CSS filter property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter)

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps you.

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 72px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#333, #fff);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<h1>Gradient text</h1>
```