# Change the lightness of a color to a specific value

Tags: css, less

I'm trying to change a specific color's lightness to a specific percentage.

For example:

`myFunction( hsl(218, 100%, 63%), 80% );`

will turn `hsl(218, 100%, 63%)` to `hsl(218, 100%, 80%)`.

I couldn't find any color operation function that does that; as `tint()` changes the saturation too, and `lighten()` is relative to the current lightness (adds to the current value).

Is there any way to achieve this using LESS?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625681/dynamically-change-color-to-lighter-or-darker-by-percentage-css-javascript

Comment: @schylake it uses `lighten`, which does not help in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I have found a workaround:

```
background-color: lighten( @color, 80% - lightness(@color) );
```

the `80%` represents the desired lightness value.

This should work with hue and saturation too:

```
// Hue:
background-color: spin( @color, 100 - hue(@color) ); // (100 degrees).

// Saturation:
background-color: saturate( @color, 80% - saturation(@color) );
```