# Add dynamic hover color

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am used to doing something like the following to give a hover color to buttons:

```
button:hover, input[type="submit"] {
    opacity: 0.8
}
```

Is there a way to do some other kind of pure-css color-transformation, such as:

```
darken: 0.2
addBlue: 0.2
```

I'm making up pseudo items, but basically seeing if there's a way to mix colors without resorting to javascript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically change color to lighter or darker by percentage CSS (Javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625681/dynamically-change-color-to-lighter-or-darker-by-percentage-css-javascript)

Comment: See the answer in the proposed duplicate that talks about CSS filters.