# How do I go about making a re-usable button in svelte?

Tags: css, button, svelte

I would like to make a re-usable button component where I can change the color for instance.
Let's say I have a base button but I want to override some properties (could be more than the background color. Ideas?

```
//Button.svelte
<script>
    export let backgroundColor;
</script>

<style>
 button {
   padding: 15px 20px;
   margin: 10px;
   background-color: #9174eb;  <-- I want this to be dynamic
   color: white;
   border-radius: 15px;
   box-shadow: 0 4px 6px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 2px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
 }

 button:hover {
  background-color: #A78BFA; <-- This as well, and if possible based on the backgroundColor value (i don't want to use sass or anything like that) 
 }
</style>


<button style="background-color : {backgroundColor}" on:click on:mouseover>
  <slot></slot>
</button>
```

`style="background-color : {backgroundColor}"` has its limitations, for instance I cannot target the hover. And with svelte we can't inject js variables in the stylesheets...

Comment: why don't you use a `className` prop and style that className with backgroundColor and so on in your css ? for eg you could have `submit` button or `secondary` or `primary` and style these classes with their background colors and hover background colors in css ? Use props for stuff like `label`, `value` , `readonly`, `disabled` ( form related examples ) important stuff.  Do not use props for styles . You would endup with 100 props for a button. Use `className` for your specific case.

Comment: Another idea is to just use global style if needed like `:global(button) { background-color: red !important;}`. See an example [here](https://svelte.dev/repl/e6658f4a8900448fbb83b6df105f9f2e?version=3.32.0).

Answer (score 1):

I like to use [CSS custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*) for this.

```html
<!-- Button.svelte -->
<script>
    export let backgroundColor;
</script>

<style>
    button {
        background-color: var(--backgroundColor);
    }
    
    button:hover {
        filter: brightness(95%);
    }
</style>

<button style="--backgroundColor: {backgroundColor}">
    <slot></slot>
</button>
```

This component can be used like so.

```html
<script>
    import Button from './Button.svelte';
</script>

<Button backgroundColor="lightgreen">
    Button
</Button>
<Button backgroundColor="#ffaaff">
    Button
</Button>
<Button backgroundColor="hsla(170, 45%, 45%, 1)">
    Button
</Button>
```

A [proposed Svelte feature](https://github.com/sveltejs/rfcs/blob/master/text/0000-style-properties.md) will make this easier.

I apply a CSS filter on hover so the hover color is slightly darker than the background color. See [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625681/dynamically-change-color-to-lighter-or-darker-by-percentage-css-javascript) for some other pure CSS options.

Comment: I tried that. But if you have many values it quickly becomes a nightmare. Interesting proposal though.