# css: make color color lighter like opacity, but not transparent

Tags: css, styles, background-color, opacity

I have a div with a certain color
`background-color: '#e86969';`

I want to make its color, as if it had opacity, but not make it 'see through'.

I tried, using chrome 'inspect' window, and see I can add 2 digits at the end but it also made it see thgouh: `background-color: '#e86969d0'`

How can I make a color 20% brighter without the opacity?

Comment: maybe here you can find solution -> [lighter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625681/dynamically-change-color-to-lighter-or-darker-by-percentage-css-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

If you convert your original hex code to `hsl`, you can then adjust the lightness part of the function.

```
background-color: hsl(0deg 73% 66%);
                               ~~~
```

Before

```css
.test {
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  background-color: hsl(0deg 73% 66%);
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

After

```css
.test {
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  background-color: hsl(0deg 73% 76%);
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use alternative solution for coloring like HSL system. In your case, #e86969 can be hsl(0, 73%, 66%). The third parameter of hsl() function is lightness.

```css
.my-div-with-hsl{
  background-color: hsl(0, 73%, 66%);
}
```

For more info:

- https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_hsl.asp
- https://www.peko-step.com/en/tool/hslrgb_en.html

Comment: _“and can't be 8 digits in CSS”_ - yes, they can. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#rgb_colors

Comment: Yeah. I see. thanks. I develop web apps for old devices and I have browser compatibility problems. Thanks again