# How can i make my color darker in pure css?

Tags: css, sass

In scss there is option to darker something in percentage for example

```
$primary-bg: #e0e0e0;
background-color: darken($primary-bg, 10);
```

but i need to do this same thing in pure css, but i can't find a way.

Comment: Pure CSS hasn't functions like sass.

Comment: I know, but is there any pure css implementation on this ?

Comment: No, it hasn't. I think it's obvious from my previous comment :-)

Comment: You said CSS has not functions like sass, you said not - there is no css way to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625681/dynamically-change-color-to-lighter-or-darker-by-percentage-css-javascript

Comment: (Duplicate easily found by typing “darken a color in pure css” into Google, btw.)

Comment: @CBroe I searched for the answers, it does not answers for darken the color - only for light the color with `hsla`. So it was not so easy what you found :)

Comment: Different answer in that same thread, https://stackoverflow.com/a/25942447/1427878, suggests using the `brighteness` filter, and with values between 0 and 1, than can also _darken_.

Answer (score -2):

**Recomended**: Calculate it manually, for example on [w3 schools color picker](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp).

If you want to darken the whole element, then you might like to use:

```
your-element {
  filter: brightness(90%);
}
```

Comment: Where i am applying color on - your-element ?

Comment: Just inject the `filter: brightness(90%);` into your code. But I prefer calculating the color, because the `filter` will affect the whole element.

Comment: Sorry, my answer wasnt correctly explained.