# How do I generate a darker color from a css hex color code?

Tags: css

I can't use `filter: brightness()`, because it darkens the whole element, including the color and background-color which are the same. Unreadable with white text on a white background.

I'm looking to darken the `background-color` value of an element and keep the `color` value the same appearance.

Comment: obviously it only works on `hover` because this selector is `:hover`, just remove that part and it will work "not on hover" :) also this will not make it darken, but brighter...

Comment: If you must work with HEX and somehow modify other things beside the HEX to make it appear darker then you should use the CSS `filter` property as this makes the most sense.

Comment: it just filters the color and the background-color which yields same values for both attributes. Ie: white on white)

Comment: That just darkens the element as a whole. so bg and fg are still the same (ie: unreadable)

Comment: You need to show us your HTML structure. Preferably in a working snippet so we can see for ourselves - it makes it much easier to advise, for example pseudo elements may help. Are you trying to darken a background or the text or both?

Comment: Is [Dynamically change color to lighter or darker by percentage CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55267265/1115360) any use? Otherwise, have you considered using SASS or LESS to write the CSS?

Comment: You could use an absolute-positioned pseudo-element "behind" the element with your HEX color and then run the filter on it

Comment: I tried that.didn't work.

Comment: I would change to hsl() which is simpler to lighten or darken stuff just by changing the luminance value

Comment: What does your code look like? What kind of element is this and what are the current/default background-color and color values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a cheap but really flexible and almost supported everywhere solution using `background-image: linear-gradient()` with a plain white / black :

```css
div{
  height:5em;
  width : 5em ;
  display:inline-block;
}

div.lighter:hover{
 background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)) ;
}

div.darker:hover{
 background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)) ;
}
```

```html
<div class='lighter' style='background-color:Red;'></div>
<div class='darker' style='background-color:Red;'></div>
```

You can change the opacity % within the `rgba` last value, or even use some gray / others colors if needed !
As `background-image` are display behind `background-color` without erasing anything, that's the solution I often use for similar case.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to darken just the background color and leave the color alone.

If you apply an explicit `z-index: 0` to the element, you may then attach to the element a `::before` pseudo-element with the following properties:

- a `background-color`
- an `opacity`, to blend the pseudo-element's `background-color` with the element's `background-color`
- a `z-index` lower than `0`, so the pseudo-element's translucent `background-color` lies *beneath* all of the element's content

---

**Working Example:**

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  line-height: 140px;
  margin-right: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
}

.darker::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -3;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
```

```html
<div>Normal Background</div>
<div class="darker">Darker Background</div>
```