# Android find if color is too close to black or white

Tags: android, colors

I have a int representation of a color. What I want to do is if this color is too black or too white, I want to set background to a default color. I want to find if the color is too close to black or white using RGB or HSV representation is fine. By too black or too white, I mean to say I can set some threshold depending on the scale. Say there is a scale from 0 to 1 where 0 is black and 1 is white, I want to reject all the colors below 0.2 and above 0.8. I tried the below code but it actually does not work. This does not work since I see some other colors also get rejected which are not shades of black or white. Please help.

```
public static boolean isWhitish(int color) {
    float[] hsv = new float[3];
    Color.colorToHSV(color, hsv);
    return hsv[2] > 0.8;
}
```

Comment: It isn't very clear what you are trying to do. Please clarify and give more information, including what you gave tried.

Comment: What do you define as 'too close'?

Answer (score 0):

First you will want to get the `HEX CODE` of your color, then you can use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679715/is-there-a-way-to-tell-if-a-html-hex-colour-is-light-or-dark) to extract the brightness of that color.

You can then use your `(brightness < .2 || brightness > .8)` to decide what to do next.

Hope this helps, good luck :-)

Comment: Thanks for responding. Thats exactly what I have tried in the code mentioned above but I see that some colors are very dark and still its brightness value does not fall in the range and vice versa :(