# Making the background-color lighter

Tags: javascript, colors, background

Is it possible, to make a specified color lighter?

for example, if I got a HEX color: `#FF0000` I 'll use something like `lighter(#FF0000);` which will return fe. `#FF3333`.

Comment: [Increase CSS brightness color on click with jquery/javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833624/increase-css-brightness-color-on-click-with-jquery-javascript)

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery and colour calculation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241618/jquery-and-colour-calculation)

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in CSS yet.

You can change this via script (dynamically):
[Generate lighter/darker color in css using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507931/generate-lighter-darker-color-in-css-using-javascript)

Or use other methods to calculate these values (static calculation):
http://www.lesscss.org